# How to bind a property of business layer class in the UI layer in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Can I bind a property of a class from the other layer to the UI. I have that class object in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much bind to the properties of any instance that is available at runtime no matter which layer it pertains to. However you might want to read [this article on the MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) on msdn.